# Pass on value from inner get statement to out get statement

Tags: angularjs, promise

Hi I am new to angular and wanted to understand promises. I have 2 http get (nested) one inside another. I want to use the value of the inside loop to form a link for the outside get statement as below.

```
        $scope.loadtable = function (task){

        var bgUrl = "cloudantlink";

        $http.get(bgUrl)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.fileTableData =[];
            for(var i =0;i<response.rows.length;i++){

                var fileUrl = "cloudantURL";

                $http.get(fileUrl, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
                .success(function (response) {

                     var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                     $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                     console.log("this is value of promise inside loop", $scope.content);


                }).error(function(data){
                });


                console.log("this is value of promise outside loop",$scope.content);

                var fileTableEntry = {
                        'download' : '<a href=\"'+$scope.content+'\">' + $scope.content+'</a>',

                    };
                    $scope.TableData.push(TableEntry);

            }
            $scope.loadTable();

        }).error(function(data){

        });


    };
```

The $scope.content value is always undefined or null outside the second loop. Could someone suggest me a way to pass the value into the first get statement.

Answer (score 0):

A `$http.get`, or any async operation will just work in the background, and any statement you write after it won't actually wait for this to finish.

If you want to run code after it's finished, you have to use the `.then` method of the `Promise` it returns.

In this case, you probably want to wait for all these operations to finish, and then call your `$scope.loadTable` and related things.

To do this, save the promises returned by the requests and wait for them with **`$q.all`** to resolve. Don't forget to add $q to your controller's dependencies.

```
var fileRequests = [];
for(...) {
   fileRequests.push($http.get(fileUrl)
   .then(function success(response) { ... return fileUrl; }))
}

$q.all(fileRequests).then(function(fileUrls) { .. $scope.loadTable() })
```

You also overwrite `$scope.content` every time, I think you meant to save the URLs in `$scope.fileTableData[i]`.

Full code:

```js
        $scope.loadtable = function (task){

        var bgUrl = "cloudantlink";

        $http.get(bgUrl)
        .success(function (response) {
            var filePromises =[];
            for(var i =0;i<response.rows.length;i++){

                var fileUrl = "cloudantURL";

                // Saving the promises
                filePromises[i] = $http.get(fileUrl, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
                .then(function success(response) {

                     var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                     // This will be the result when the promise is resolved
                     return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

                }, function error(data) {
                });


            }
            
            // Waiting for the promises
            $q.all(filePromises).then(function(fileUrls) 
            {
              // fileUrls contain the results returned by the success callback
              $scope.TableData = fileUrls.map(function(url) {
                return { 'download' : '<a href=\"'+url+'\">' + url+'</a>', };
              })
              $scope.loadTable();
            })
            

        }).error(function(data){

        });
```

Comment: I dont think I can do that as the reponse type is a array buffer used to create a BLOB url from the inner get statement. I also tried with q.all but did not work for me.  The value is present in the loop, but it loads only the second time if i navigate between tabs. It does not load the first time.

Comment: In your code, the success callback inside the loop runs _after_ both the `$scope.TableData.push(TableEntry);` and the `$scope.loadTable();` line. This has nothing to do with the response type and what you do with it. You have to either move the fileTableEntry creation code into the success callback, or store those blob urls in an array and add them after the promises are resolved, in the $q.all callback.

Comment: The problem of not being able to move the $scope.TableData.push(TableEntry); and the $scope.loadTable(); inside the second get is because I want to add more rows for table creation from the response of first get statement. Also could you be a little more detailed on the code part? I did use promises, but what you are suggesting might be different.

Comment: Added a full example, hope it helps. The point is, a `$http.get` or any async operation will just work in the background, and any statement you write after it won't actually wait for it to finish. If you want to run code after it's finished, you have to use the `.then` method of the promise it returns.

Comment: This does not return me the trusted urls like it used to return previously and hence I am not able to embed the url in it   `sce url Object { $$unwrapTrustedValue: TrustedValueHolderType/this.$$unwrapTrustedValue() }`
                                                                                                                `this is file requests Object { status: 1, pending: undefined, value: Object, processScheduled: false } `
`this is the file  Object { data: ArrayBuffer, status: 200, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }`

Comment: I just dont use the value from second get to form the table.. I also use the response of the first get to form the table. With this way I am unable to use the response of the First get statement as it returns that response.data is undefined